# Остановка и рестарт таймера Android

Tags: java, android

Есть такой код:

```
mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
mTimer = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new CountDownTimer(130000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimer.setText("Осталось" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimer.setText("");
            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

Как создать кнопку чтобы можно было: остановить или рестартнуть таймер?

Comment: А этот код работает? Если работает  пробовали не анонимную реализацию таймера делать, а создать объект, хранить его. Он кликом запускать метод с параметром, от которого зависит "стартим" мы таймер или останавливаем?

Answer (score 2):

```
mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
mTimer = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(130000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTimer.setText("Осталось" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        mTimer.setText("");
    }
};

mButton.setOnClickListener(timer);
timer.start();
```

Теперь определите где вы будете его останавливать и сделайте

```
timer.cancel();
```